# Could I use a pre-built CMS or should I build one from the ground-up?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

I am working on a project for a client that started out as a simple CMS with pages, posts, and a directory. The client is constantly expanding the scope of this project with requirements for customization of just about everything. As a single developer, I am having trouble keeping up with the clients time-table. I have googled for software packages that might already exist that proved the features my client needs but I have not found anything. Does anyone know of any pre-built software that allows for the following customization or at least better words to describe this type of package?

Here are some examples of the customization that is requested:

- A page or directory listing needs to be formatted from an admin-defined template. Within this template there needs to be admin-defined sections that contain admin-defined data types. (This is so the look and feel of the site can be maintained while users can easily build content, add listings, and etc.)
- Advertising-tiles need to be able to be defined and populated globally and at page level.
- All user generated content, pages, posts, and directory listings need to be associated with user and have flexibility to show all other user generated content for inter-linking between same users content.
- Site would need billing/e-commerce system for premium listings, premium posts, advertising tiles, and etc.
- Approval system for all user added or edited content (pages, posts, directory listings, etc.)

(asp.net and mvc are definitely preferable)

Answer (score 4):

> Site would need billing/e-commerce system

This is the number one reason you should not roll your own. Find an established CMS and take the time to learn to use it.

Answer (score 0):

My dear friend,
                       I've read your question & I may suggest that you should try some open-source CMS software with your own which can generate, display admin-generated templates & other stuffs.
                      You should use the

- Pre-bulit CMS software for keeping track of pages.
- Your own small customized cms for maintaining templates.
- osCommerce (open-source) for eCommerce support.

Answer (score 0):

I've not had a change to use it, and I'm not sure if it will provide for you all of your demands or not, but I've heard a lot of great things about the project. Have you tried the open source project [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)?